# Maven won't download dependencies

Tags: java, maven

How to retrieve dependencies in Maven from pom.xml file? When I press `compile` or `install` it has no effect.
[image]

Comment: That "Build success" means your code was compiled, hence the dependency was downloaded. Check your maven repository and you'll find it there.

Comment: C:\Users\<yourUserName>\.m2\repository

Answer (score 0):

You can check your maven dependencies by pressing Ctrl+Alt+U. If the library is successfully imported into you project, it should be under dependencies tree.
If not, try to delete the .idea folder, reimport the project or click on File -> Invalidate Caches. That might help